# Get value from unknown json

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I need only the values .how to get value from these json

```
-wafer,
-Compound Chocolate,
-Praline Chcolate
etc.....
```

In this a main problem is "subcategory" and its value is taken from database its change according to database

```
[{"subcategory":"Wafer"},{"subcategory":"Compound Chocolate"},{"subcategory":"Praline Chcolate"},{"subcategory":"Cookies"},{"subcategory":"Toffee"},{"subcategory":"Eclair"},{"subcategory":"Fruit Chews"}]
```

each json has a value like subcategory

Comment: you can use for(i in s){ console.log(s[i]["subcategory"]); }; if the property name "subcategory" is going to be constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KGms7/

```
var str = '[{"subcategory":"Wafer"},{"subcategory":"Compound Chocolate"},{"subcategory":"Praline Chcolate"},{"subcategory":"Cookies"},{"subcategory":"Toffee"},{"subcategory":"Eclair"},{"subcategory":"Fruit Chews"}]';
var jsn = JSON.parse(str);

var arr = [];
for(var i in jsn) {
    arr.push(jsn[i].subcategory);
}
alert(arr);
```

Comment: What about `if (i instanceof jsn) {}` ?)

Comment: subcategory is not a permanent value its change according to database fields